# Accusative plural vs Accusative masculine in Lückentest confusion

Tags: grammar-identification, grammatical-number

> Die zunehmende Urbanisierung der Industrienationen, also der Trend, dass immer mehr Menschen meist auf der Suche nach einer besseren Zukunft d(ie) ländlichen Reg(ionen) eines Landes verlassen und sich in Städten ansiedeln, ...

> Die Tradition des klassichen Handwerks, Gesellen nach Abschluss ihrer Ausbildung für mehrere Jahre auf Wanderschaft zu schicken, um in anderen Regi(onen) des Landes oder im Ausland Beruserfahrung zu sammeln und sich später als "Meister" zu qualifizieren,...

The text had the bracketted part deleted, and we had to fill it in. In both cases, I assumed it should be "Region" but the answer was actually the plural. Could someone explain why?

Answer (score 1):

It's *die Region*, hence **feminine.**

> d(ie) ländlichen Reg(ionen)

If you made *Region* singular, it must also be *ländliche*, as the feminine singular accusative weak adjective ending is *-e*, not *-en*.

> in anderen Regi(onen)

This must be plural simply for the reason that you needed an article or similar determiner if it was singular. This is from the semantics in your context which doesn't treat *die Region* as a concept.

But you can also tell it from the adjective declination. This is a location so it must be dative. But the dative singular feminine strong adjective ending is *-er*, not *-en*. So this can't be singular.

Comment: "This is from the semantics in your context which doesn't treat die Region as a concept." could you explain this?

Comment: You need an article or similar determiner to mark a noun as singular. If you don't do that, it's either plural, or a mass noun, or a concept. For example: *Lernen macht Spaß.* treats both *das Lernen* and *der Spaß* as concepts.

Comment: What do you mean by a "mass noun"?

Comment: For example *der Staub* is a mass noun. You don't count but measure it.

Comment: My mind is blown.

Comment: Well, you could say *die Stäube* but that would mean there's different kinds of dust you are talking about. For example zinc oxides dust and lead oxides dust.